# Uploading csv not working on Server Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

Here is my code

```
function importcsv()
{
    $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
    $data['error'] = ''; //initialize image upload error array to empty
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // If upload failed, display error

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }
    else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path = './uploads/' . $file_data['file_name'];
        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
                    'birthday' => $row['birthday'],
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                );
                $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url() . 'csv');

            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);

        }
        else $data['error'] = "Error occured";
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }
}
```

On localhost uploading working fine but on server I get "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed".

Mysql all privilege are active also file permission 755. I also tried changing permission to 777 but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please copy your code into the question. In a year your pastebin will have faded away and this question will help nobody.

Answer (score 0):

The message basically say that the server is not allowed to receive this type of file. Probabily you need to modify the server configuration to enable the upload of CSV files. (look at the configuration of your localhost, since it is working)

Comment: Can u explain how to modify the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the mimes.php file in application/config/mimes.php and replace the line for the csv by this one:

```
'csv' => array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values'
```

OR  config.php change this to

```
 'allowed_types' => 'text/plain|text|csv|csv',
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with replace 'csv' on mimes.php file in application/config/mimes.php

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'),
```